# Android: Error in substracting two integers in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
TextView tvBalAchieve = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvBalAchieve);
```

I've retrieve some data from sqlite database (Those are integers) and substract them set the result in a text view as follows.

```
tvBalAchieve.setText(Integer.toString(lstTargetAchieveVal.get(0).getTargetVal() - lstTargetAchieveVal.get(0).getAchievedVal()));
```

Here `lstTargetAchieveVal` is an object array list. And this is my entity class segment.

```
public class WMTargetExecAchieveSummary {
private int targetVol;
private int targetVal;
private int achievedVol;
private int achievedVal;
private int returnVol;
private int returnVal;
private String updatedOn;

public int getTargetVol() {
    return targetVol;
}

public void setTargetVol(int targetVol) {
    this.targetVol = targetVol;
}

public int getTargetVal() {
    return targetVal;
}

public void setTargetVal(int targetVal) {
    this.targetVal = targetVal;
}

public int getAchievedVol() {
    return achievedVol;
}

public void setAchievedVol(int achievedVol) {
    this.achievedVol = achievedVol;
}

public int getAchievedVal() {
    return achievedVal;
}

public void setAchievedVal(int achievedVal) {
    this.achievedVal = achievedVal;
}
```

This doesn't give any error message. But the result is the value of `lstTargetAchieveVal.get(0).getTargetVal().`

Actually it's not substracting. I am doing all of these things inside the onCreateView method(inside a fragment). Can anyone please be so kind enough to explain what's going on here and how can I correct it.

Comment: I strongly recommend you learn to use a debugger.

Comment: may be you are not getting the second value from which you are trying to subtract. check with debugger.

Comment: What is the exception trace?

Comment: One possible reason would also be if lstTargetAchieveVal.get(0).getAchievedVal() is ZERO, then targetVal - 0 = targetVal. And really, use debugger to check the the values you're getting.

Comment: Thanx all.Problem solved. I used debugger. @Melquiades you're correct, lstTargetAchieveVal.get(0).getAchievedVal() is ZERO.